# java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject simple-json

Tags: java, json, simplejson

I am getting strange problem while trying to parse a simple json using simple-json by google.

Here is my code which is not working:

```
String s = args[0].toString();
JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(s);
```

When I execute, it will give me the exception `java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject`

But when I hard code json directly like below its working fine. Wat could be the reason?

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse("{\"application\":\"admin\",\"keytype\":\"PRODUCTION\",\"callbackUrl\":\"qwerewqr;ewqrwerq;qwerqwerq\",\"authorizedDomains\":\"ALL\",\"validityTime\":\"3600000\",\"retryAfterFailure\":true}");
```

UPDATE

When I print s, it will give me the output below:

```
"{\"application\":\"admin\",\"keytype\":\"PRODUCTION\",\"callbackUrl\":\"qwerewqr;ewqrwerq;qwerqwerq\",\"authorizedDomains\":\"ALL\",\"validityTime\":\"3600000\",\"retryAfterFailure\":true}"
```

Comment: Maybe it's because s was in a wrong format? Or do you get a different error in that case? In your second example, try to put in an invalid JSON string, like "test123" and see the error.

Comment: Could you change and debug it with Object obj = new JSONParser().parse(s) instead of JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(s)

Comment: @aegean yes that is wroking.. thanks i just wondering how could I get print the json elements with it?

Comment: @PhilippMurry when i am giving "test123" its giving Unexpected character (t) at position 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran this through eclipse by providing `arguments` in `run configuration`.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = args[0].toString();
        System.out.println("=>" + s);
        try {
            JSONObject json = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(s);
            System.out.println(json);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Output**

```
=>{"application":"admin","keytype":"PRODUCTION","callbackUrl":"qwerewqr;ewqrwerq;qwerqwerq","authorizedDomains":"ALL","validityTime":"3600000","retryAfterFailure":true}


{"validityTime":"3600000","callbackUrl":"qwerewqr;ewqrwerq;qwerqwerq","application":"admin","retryAfterFailure":true,"authorizedDomains":"ALL","keytype":"PRODUCTION"}
```

Comment: thanks .. this is  working but my problem is when i invoke from args[0].toString(); then not working..

Comment: @RoshanWijesena - Print out what you get from args[0].  You SHOULD NOT see any escapes.  Presumably `parse` returns a String error message (which you should test with `instanceof`) when it encounters an error.

Comment: @HotLicks thanks. When i am print it out it is giving me "{\"application\":\"admin\",\"keytype\":\"PRODUCTION\",\"callbackUrl\":\"qwerewqr;ewqrwerq;qwerqwerq\",\"authorizedDomains\":\"ALL\",\"validityTime\":\"3600000\",\"retryAfterFailure\":true}"

Comment: @RoshanWijesena answer edited, as per your requirement

Comment: Yep, the escapes do not belong there.  It isn't a C string, so escapes may not be required (depending on the OS and command analyzer used).

Comment: +1 guys, that could be the reason.. any idea how to remove those escape characters programmatic ally ?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the string is a valid JSON. You can user JSONObject parameterized constructor with the given string to convert the JSON string to a valid JSON object.

For example,

```
try {
    String jsonString = " {'application':'admin','keytype':'PRODUCTION','callbackUrl':'qwerewqr;ewqrwerq;qwerqwerq','authorizedDomains':'ALL','validityTime':3600000,'retryAfterFailure':true}";
 
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    String application = data.getString("application"); //gives admin
    String keytype = data.getString("keytype"); //gives PRODUCTION
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue

```
   package com.test;

   import org.json.JSONObject;
   import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
   import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

   public class JSONTest {    

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String s = args[0];
            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject((String) new JSONParser().parse(s));
                System.out.println(json);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }
   }
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
package com.test;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class JSONTest {    

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String s = args[0];
            try {
                JSONObject json = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(s);
                System.out.println(json);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Then on command line

```
java -classpath  ".;json-simple-1.1.1.jar" com.test.JSONTest {\"application\":\"admin\",\"keytype\":\"PRODUCTION\",\"callbackUrl\":\"qwerewqr;ewqrwerq;qwerqwerq\",\"authorizedDomains\":\"ALL\",\"validityTime\":\"3600000\",\"retryAfterFailure\":true}
```

The out put is

```
{"validityTime":"3600000","callbackUrl":"qwerewqr;ewqrwerq;qwerqwerq","application":"admin","retryAfterFailure":true,"authorizedDomains":"ALL","keytype":"PRODUCTION"}
```