# (Android json) java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I parser String to JSON using simplejson.

Here my json string.

```
"{\"Result\":[{\"trxCode\":\"Y\",\"trxMsg\":\"Success\"}],\"Table1\":[{\"TNS_NM\":\"TEST\",\"USR_ID\":\"TESTER\",\"USR_PWD\":\"TEST\",\"DB_IP\":\"TEST_IP\"}]}"
```

I need to parse this.

So here my code

```
private static Map<String, Object> convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
{
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    try
    {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(line);
        String json = sb.toString();
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(json); // error occur here

        result.put("trxMsg", jsonObject);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        result.put("error", e.getMessage());
        //  java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject
    }
    finally
    {
        inputStream.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

But If I put the string value directly, no error occurs.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse("{\"Result\":[{\"trxCode\":\"Y\",\"trxMsg\":\"Success\"}],\"Table1\":[{\"TNS_NM\":\"TEST\",\"USR_ID\":\"TESTER\",\"USR_PWD\":\"TEST\",\"DB_IP\":\"TEST_IP\"}]}");
```

Even, It work.

```
String json = "{\"Result\":[{\"trxCode\":\"Y\",\"trxMsg\":\"Success\"}],\"Table1\":[{\"TNS_NM\":\"TEST\",\"USR_ID\":\"TESTER\",\"USR_PWD\":\"TEST\",\"DB_IP\":\"TEST_IP\"}]}";
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(json);
```

But these not work..

```
String json = sb.toString();
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(json);
// or...
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(sb.toString());
```

I know my question is same [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567041/java-lang-string-cannot-be-cast-to-org-json-simple-jsonobject-simple-json).

But that answer can't apply to my code.

Answer is parse in Main.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { }
```

But my case, connect is done by the user's button click.

So I cannot be used, and I need for android

I couldn't find a answer anywhere else.

please help me.

Comment: have you tried with `JSONObject` parameters like JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);

Comment: I not use 'import org.json.JSONObject', I use 'import org.json.simple.JSONObject'. So that occuers type missmatch error. (Required type=Map, Provided=String).

Comment: And 'import org.json.JSONObject' is occuer same cast error.

Comment: String json = sb.toString();
String json2 = (json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
json2 = json2.replace("\\", "");
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json2);

I answer myself. it work for me.

Comment: refer this.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267910/jsonexception-value-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject